# Package to use with React native to subscribe to notifications/chat/etc provided by Laravel-implemented API

Tags: php, mysql, react

My friend is building a backend with php laravel framework and he is building an API to connect the backend with a React native app.

Regarding Notifications, Chat and other form of data that need a kind of subscription I need to know the best package to use to keep track of any data change.

Comment: You will connect to the API your friend is building, right? Not directly to PHP/MySQL.

Comment: Yes, all CRUD functions on application will be implemented through API

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Whole App data will be completely fetched through connected Laravel API